# How to overlay with text

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `\num` in LaTeX documents to automatically number paragraphs when the *.pdf is generated.  I am trying to write a function that will display the numbers within Emacs using an overlay.  My `toggle-num-block` function partially works if I use a symbol such as an upside-down triangle (e.g., `"\u25be"`), but does *not* work when I use a variable such as `n` (which is a number that increments each time `\num` is found).  Any pointers on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

To test my function, I'm using the space just to the right of `\num` to place the overlay.  If I use `(overlay-put (make-overlay beg end) 'display  "\u25be"))` instead of `(overlay-put (make-overlay beg end) 'display n))`, the upside-down triangle can be seen.  Instead of the upside-down triangle, however, I'd prefer to have numbers that incrementally increase -- 1, 2, 3, etc.

My document looks like this:

```
\num    Every good boy deserves fudge.

\num    I'm not a fig . . . .
```

I would like the function `toggle-num-block` to be able to switch back and forth from the above-example to the following example:

```
1.      Every good boy deserves fudge.

2.      I'm not a fig . . . .
```

Here is my rough draft:

```lisp
(require 'outline)

(defun toggle-num-block ()
"When FLAG is non-nil, hide the region.  Otherwise make it visible."
(interactive)
  (let ((n 0))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\num" nil t)
        (setq n (1+ n))
        (let* (
            (flag (not (get-char-property (match-end 0) 'invisible)))
            (beg (match-end 0))
            (end (+ (match-end 0) 1)))
          (outline-flag-region beg end flag)
          (cond
            (flag
              (overlay-put (make-overlay beg end) 'display n)) ;; "\u25be"
            (t
              (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end)))) )))))
```

---

Based upon the helpful answer of @Tyler below (greatly appreciated), here is the revised function that now works as expected:

```lisp
(require 'outline)

(defun toggle-num-block ()
"When FLAG is non-nil, hide the region.  Otherwise make it visible."
(interactive)
  (let ((n 0))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward "\\\\begin\{document\}" nil t)
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\num" nil t)
        (setq n (1+ n))
        (let* ((flag (not (get-char-property (match-beginning 0) 'invisible)))
               (beg (match-beginning 0))
               (end (match-end 0)))
          (outline-flag-region beg end flag)
          (cond
            (flag
              (overlay-put
                (make-overlay beg end)
                  'display
                    (concat (number-to-string n) "."))) 
            (t
             (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end)))))))))
```

Comment: symbol's function definition is void: outline-flag-region. Can you give us a complete MWE?

Comment: @Tyler -- `(require 'outline)`.  Sorry for my not thinking about that -- that is one of the libraries I load every time Emacs starts.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems - you set `beg` to `match-end` instead of `match-beginning`. And you need to convert `n` into a string:

```el
(require 'outline)
(defun toggle-num-block ()
"When FLAG is non-nil, hide the region.  Otherwise make it visible."
(interactive)
  (let ((n 0))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\num" nil t)
        (setq n (1+ n))
        (let* ((flag (not (get-char-property (match-end 0) 'invisible)))
               (beg (match-beginning 0))
               (end (+ (match-end 0) 1)))
          (outline-flag-region beg end flag)
          (cond
            (flag
              (overlay-put (make-overlay beg end) 
                           'display (concat (number-to-string n) ". "))) 
            (t
             (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end)))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trouble-shooting my function -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)

Comment: No problem. I've been wondering about how overlays work, this gave me an excuse to find out! I updated my answer to add a '.' after n.

Comment: I made a few minor enhancements to the code (appended to the question) to better handle picking up the `'invisible` character property -- i.e., `(match-beginning 0)` seems to work more reliably than `(match-ending 0)`.  I had borrowed portions of the code from `org-mode`, which folded areas *subsequent to* the beginning regexp (in this case `\num`), and in that circumstance, the ending of the regexp was actually the beginning of the folded region -- the situation is reversed in the current example.  I also reduced `end` to just `(match-end 0)` and I'm only concatenating `"."` instead of `". "`